# windows service startup timeout

Tags: windows-services, timeout, startup

Is there a way to set a different value for service startup timeout per service?
I can change it using the ServicesPipeTimeout registry key, but it's per machine (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/824344).

At the moment the only thing I thought about was to do all the time-consuming startup actions in a different thread.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It's good practice to finish starting your service as fast as possible. So, during the *start* state, do only what you absolutely need to acknowledge it started successfully; and do the rest later. If the *start* is still a lengthy process, use [SetServiceStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686241.aspx) periodically to inform the *Service Control Manager* that you have not yet finished, so it does not time-out your service.

Comment: Bear in mind though that if there is another service dependent on your own then it will probably expect your service to be fully-functional once it has posted SERVICE_RUNNING. That is a good reason to complete _all_ of your initialisation before posting SERVICE_RUNNING, and asking for more time if necessary with SetServiceStatus.

Answer (score 82):

I agree with Romulo on finishing to start your service as soon as possible. However, if you need the time and you are using .NET Framework 2.0 or later, you might consider ServiceBase.RequestAdditionalTime() method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.requestadditionaltime.aspx

```cs
protected override void OnStart()
{
    this.RequestAdditionalTime(10000);
    // do your stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot! I've got some old code and needed to get it to run ...

Comment: Warning, possible caveat: "What the documentation for HostControl.RequestAdditionalTime fails to state is that you can only ask for a max of 60 or 120 seconds. Otherwise it ignores your request." (from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589686/topshelf-timeout-issue, haven't verified it, but worth considering)

Answer (score 4):

Simply do timeintensive stuff in another thread

```cs
   protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        var task = new Task(() =>
        {
            // Do stuff
        });
        base.OnStart(args);
        task.Start();
    }
```

Comment: You have to be careful here because if `// Do stuff` throws an exception, it will be swallowed instead of stopping/crashing the service, which you may actually want so that you know the service is not working, instead of it "running", but not actually doing anything or working properly.

Answer (score 1):

I also had to deal with a service which may takes a few seconds/minutes to have a good Start.  When the service starts, it tries to connect to a SQL Server.  However, when the whole server was restarted , my service was starting BEFORE SQL Server.  (I know about the Service dependency but it dont apply to my situation for a particular reason....).  I tried to do a loop trying 10 times to connect to SQL Server, but Windows was killing my service before the 2nd try, because of the Timeout.

**My solution** : I added a Timer in the "onStart()" of my service.  Then, the "onTick()" method of the service was trying 10 times to connect to the SQL Server (with a waiting of 30 in it). No more Timeout at startup.

So basically,

- My service starts in 5 seconds.
- A timer is launched 10 seconds after the service is
  started.
- The timer tries 10 times [waiting 30 seconds each time] to
  connect to the SQL Server.
- If it succeed, the timer will disable itself, if not (after 10 try), I stop the service.

Note the more elegant way to resolve the problem but maybe some part of my solution may help anybody in the same situation than me,