# Is there a way to increase windows service startup timeout for a specific service?

Tags: c#, windows-services, timeout, startup

I need to increase a startup timeout for one of my windows services (startup=automatic) to be able to start it after a reboot. It starts normally if I start it manually or use `startup=delayed` type, but I would like to keep it `automatic`
I can increase it by changing `ServicesPipeTimeout` registry key, but that will increase timeout for all windows services, whereas I want to do it for only one specific service.

Another solution is to use `RequestAdditionalTime` in my `OnStartup` method I found it here 
[windows service startup timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216401/windows-service-startup-timeout),
however again it does not suit me because it seems `OnStart` does not even run at all, probably windows needs some time to load different dlls before starting the service and 30 seconds is just not enough after a PC reboot.

Is there another way to do it maybe setting some other registry key-values to increase timeout for only one service?

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216401/windows-service-startup-timeout

Answer (score 2):

[You can modify the timeout value in the registry](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922918).

---

```
1. Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.
2. Locate and then click the following registry subkey:
 - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control
3. In the right pane, locate the ServicesPipeTimeout entry.

**Note**: If the ServicesPipeTimeout entry does not exist, you must create it. To do this, follow these steps:

 - On the Edit menu, point to New, and then click DWORD Value.
 - Type ServicesPipeTimeout, and then press ENTER. 
4. Right-click ServicesPipeTimeout, and then click Modify.
5. Click Decimal, type 60000, and then click OK.
 - This value represents the time in milliseconds before a service times out.
6. Restart the computer.
```

---

Comment: This method will increase timeout for all services, but I need to do it only for one specific service, and leave others intact.

Comment: @MykhailoSeniutovych Hi there, Have you found any solution for the problem ?

Comment: @MykhailoSeniutovych Have the same issue as well